# how to make your loop display "stop" at the end when the random number is less than 100

Tags: java, loops

i am generating a random number which if it is more than 100 the loop continues and if it is lesser than 100 the loop stops

```
Random rand = new Random();
int r = rand.nextInt(200) ;

if(r < 100 );{
    System.out.println( r + " stop");
    while(r > 100);{
        r = rand.nextInt(200);
        System.out.println( r +"continue");
   }    
}
```

I expect that the program will end at the word "stop" because it is less than 100

Comment: Move your `if` inside the loop and `break` when it ocurrs.

Comment: Typo.  You have an infinite loop because you put a semicolon right after the `while` condition, meaning it's an empty loop body that never modifies the `r` value.  Remove the semicolon.  You did the same thing for your `if` earlier.

Comment: If you explain why you want to do this, someone may suggest an better alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your logic in the loop, you can easily end it when the condition is met. You only need to assign and check r once, and a minimum of once hence the do-while loop is your best bet.

```
Random rand = new Random();
int r ;
do{
    r = rand.nextInt(200);
    if(r < 100 ){
        break;
    }
    System.out.println( r +"continue");
}while(true);
System.out.println( r + " stop");
```

You can also use a for loop too! This will assign r in the first iteration and check it, then iterate if the condition isn't met, then assign r again and check it again.

```
Random rand = new Random();
int r ;
for(r = rand.nextInt(200); r >= 100; r = rand.nextInt(200)){
    System.out.println( r +"continue");
}
System.out.println( r + " stop");
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need 2 conditionals; while "wrong" => try again:

```
SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();
int r = rand.nextInt(200) ;

while(r < 100) {
    System.out.println(r + "continue");
    r = rand.nextInt(200);
}

System.out.println(r + " stop");
```

If you only care about the result, you could use a generator:

```
final SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();
final IntSupplier gen = () -> rand.nextInt(200);

final int r = IntStream.generate(gen) // note: streams are lazy
        .filter(i -> i >= 100)
        .findAny()
        .orElse(0);

System.out.println(r);
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the if condition inside the while loop and use a jump statement such as break, to terminate loop iteration as soon as it encounters a no < than 100.

You are putting a ';' after the while loop, so the contents inside the loop won't be executed.

Answer (score 0):

If `r`, set at the second line, is less than a hundred, then you will see the "stop" printout and the while loop will never be entered -- it will have no effect

If the second line gives a value greater than or equal to a hundred, you will not enter that `if` block at all, and so also not enter the `while` block.

Note that you were missing some closing brackets, which I added.

I am also ignoring the semicolon after the `while`, which I assume is a typo -- please remove it.